# Error trying to update TextBox via a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'd like to update TextBox.Text in a thread but it doesn't work and I get this error (In French) :

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'Opération inter-threads non valide : le contrôle 'TextBOX' a fait l'objet d'un accès à partir d'un thread autre que celui sur lequel il a été créé.'

In English (Google Translate) it looks like :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid inter-thread operation: The' TextBOX 'control has been accessed from a thread other than the one on which it was created.'

How can I do so ?
Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ace
{
    public partial class Checker : Form
    {

        public Checker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Checker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            status("Checking ...");
            check();
            status("Done !");
        }

        public void check()
        {
            int threads = 10;
            var lines = File.ReadLines("test.txt");
            Parallel.ForEach(lines, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, line =>
            {
                TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + line + "\n"; // THIS LINE
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call *Invoke()* on the component, when attempting to modify it from another thread than the UI thread.

Change:

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + line + "\n"; // THIS LINE
```

To:

```
TextBox.Invoke((Delegate)(() =>
{
    TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + line + "\n";
})));
```

Also you can change:

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + line + "\n";
```

To:

```
TextBox.Text += line + "\n";
```

I want to warn you about your code though. It's not thread-safe and race-conditions can happen.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, but I get this error, how to fix it ? Thanks ! `Can not convert lambda expression to 'Delegate' type because it does not act as delegate type`

Comment: Sorry. Updated my answer, it should work now. Forgot to cast the expression to `Delegate`

Comment: Same. :/ @Bauss